# Is there no timeout_exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception, std

I'm looking for a std::timeout_exception in the standard c++ lib (stdexcept). I haven't found one.

Ok - I can build my own:

```
class timeout_exception : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

Is there really no timeout exception in the standard lib? Does I have to define it myself?

Comment: you need to define your own class

Comment: What do you consider to be a viable timeout_exception? The name? Your definition has no other differences from `runtime_error`. Where should the standard library use it? If nowhere, why should the standard library define an exception it never uses?

Comment: @Jodocus : He can catch `timeout_except` explicitly, and let other runtime errors through.

Comment: @MartinBonner I know, but why should it be part of the standard library?

Comment: This is a very good case for defining your own, as you've done. You want to be able to handle different exceptions differently, and you can catch them in different blocks. Makes sense. If you're coming from a .NET background, maybe you expect the standard lib to have a lot of things pre-rolled, but C++ has minimal pre-baked objects. But you are given the tools required to build your own!

Comment: Why is it so surprising? C++ standard does not define anything that can ever timeout (none that I know of). As such, there's nothing that could potentially throw such exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no `std::timeout_exception`.  There is no need for the standard to define it, as there is nothing in the standard library which could throw it.

The obvious candidate is `std::timed_lock`, but `try_lock_for` and `try_lock_until` just return false.

Your definition looks fine.